# File Not Found Error when view the workflows for an Item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

File Not found error is appearing for list items. But sometimes, If I refreshed the same URL It will open the workflow list

**And from the Log file I extracted below**

> Mapping URI from 
>   'http://APP:80/SecurityService/_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx?List={AC011C49-1B37-4FF7-A62D-8C4551F4C2F4}&WorkflowInstanceName=016dced6-7e43-4821-a4a3-313684c20a38' to 
>   'http://APP23/SecurityService/_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx?List=%7BAC011C49-1B37-4FF7-A62D-8C4551F4C2F4%7D&WorkflowInstanceName=016dced6-7e43-4821-a4a3-313684c20a38'

In SharePoint designer also I cannot see the workflow list and Its says "There are no items to show in this view."

I have checked the services in app server related to Workflow manager Everything seems up and running.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the workflow a SharePoint 2013 platform workflow?

Does this issue happen on a specific one or all workflows?

If you are using SharePoint 2013 platform, you can try to re-register workflow via [Register-SPWorkflowService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/register-spworkflowservice?view=sharepoint-ps).

After that, create a new SharePoint 2013 workflow and test again.

Comment: This happened in all the workflow.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the Workflow Service Proxy from Central Admin did the trick for me. But doing that removed the ability to create 2013 Workflows.

Comment: what will happen to existing 2013 workflows?????

Comment: I haven't tested, but i'm asuming those won't work anymore. You'll still have the 2010 option available.

Comment: No sujin I have lots of workflows in 2013 version. I noticed this happened because of the Request manager in sharePoint